# Regular Expression to check for repeating characters

Tags: regex

I had to create a regular expression that allows in either the text "*ALL" (case independent) *OR* characters in the ranges a-z, A-Z and 0-9 which must be 17 characters long. This I have done without any problems:

```
^([\*][Aa][Ll][Ll]|[a-zA-Z0-9]{17})$
```

The problem I am having is how to alter it so that it picks up if just the same character is entered a number of times (e.g. 17 x's).

Comment: If you're using egrep you can make the search case insensitive by using the flag '-l'. That would enable you to simplify your expression along the lines of norbitheeviljester's answer.

Answer (score 11):

In order to do that you'd need to use the catching parentheses. It's a concept in which whatever you surround with parentheses will be captured into the memory of the regular expression parser.

So if you have the following expression:

```
(\w)\1+
```

it will match a single word character:  `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` and the same character(s) after it. Because the parentheses caught and memorised what was stored inside them.

So in your case:

```
^((?:\*[aA][lL]{2})|([a-zA-Z0-9])\1{17})$
```

where the (?:) is a non capturing parentheses.

You can also use the `\1{1,17}` construct which means the character should be repeated from 1 to 17 times.

On another note I think that using a regular expression here is a bit overkill.
You should probably save the string, lowercase it then compare it to '*all'. If it's not equal then you can use the regular expression `^([a-zA-Z0-9])\1{17}$` for A LOT more readability.

Comment: You have a bracket wrong. You need to group the alternation like in the question, otherwise the anchors belong not to the whole expression. Means the `^` belongs only to the first alternative ==> `^(?:\*[aA][lL]{2}|([a-zA-Z0-9])\1{17})$`

Answer (score 4):

you can use a backreference, if your implementation language supports it

try `([a-zA-Z0-9])\1{16}`

the `\1` refers to the previously matched group `()`

Answer (score 3):

### **[Regexr](http://regexr.com?321h9)**:

#### Non-capturing:

```
^(?:[\*][Aa][Ll][Ll]|([a-zA-Z0-9])\1{16})$
```

Second part of the regex, `([a-zA-Z0-9])\1{16}`, matches an alphanumeric character and then repeats same 16 more times.

#### Capturing:

If you want to capture whole thing, remove `?:` (which means don't capture this group) and change `\1` to `\2`:

```
^([\*][Aa][Ll][Ll]|([a-zA-Z0-9])\2{16})$
```

### Matches:

```
*ALL
*all
all
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa # 17 times same character
```

### Doesn't match:

```
all
ALL
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa    # 16 times same character
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa  # 18 times same character
ababababababababa   # 17 times different characters
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one-

```
*[Aa][Ll][Ll]|([a-zA-Z0-9])\1{16}
```