# first 8 letters are the same regex

Tags: regex

I am trying to design a regex where the first 8 letters are the same.

Examples:

```
oooooooo34reefe
aaaaaaaafsfdew4regr4
llllllllsftgerf
qqqqqqqqdhiocdnsfncdops
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regular Expression to check for repeating characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12258622/regular-expression-to-check-for-repeating-characters)

Comment: and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240504/regular-expression-to-match-string-starting-with-stop (anchor to beginning with `^`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this [Regex](https://regex101.com/r/51fUDQ/1):

```
^(.)\1{7}
```

- `^` is the start of the line. You would get [more matches](https://regex101.com/r/OFlgbC/1) otherwise.
- `(.)` matches a character and captures it (in case the `^` is used, it becomes the first character)
- `\1` express that the captured character must occur there
- `{7}` ... seven times (since the first one has been already matched, 7 out of 8 left)